# How to make CPLEX NOT output to terminal window in Julia

Tags: cplex, julia-jump

I am trying to silent CPLEX messages and so far I manage this:

```
model = Model(CPLEX.Optimizer)
JuMP.set_parameter(model, "CPX_PARAM_MIPDISPLAY", 0)
```

But I am still getting some messages like this one:

```
Version identifier: 12.10.0.0 | 2019-11-26 | 843d4de2ae
CPXPARAM_MIP_Display                             0
```

How can I completely turn off CPLEX logging in console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `set_silent`. Documentation: https://jump.dev/JuMP.jl/stable/manual/models/#Turn-off-output